# Modals not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to code a game in jQuery, and I've gotten most of the basics down.

I'm currently working on the html file to go along with it, but I'm getting code errors for, as far as I can see, no apparent reason.

Could anyone please help?

I'm using bootstrap located here: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/superhero/bootstrap.min.css

My code is here:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="onLoadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Welcome to Electronics: Evolution Duo!</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>You are on your way to become the next big electronics producer, but first you must name your store. How will people know what store to go to if it doesn't have a name?</p>
            <br />
            <p>It would also be wise to put your name on the deed to your store.</p>
             <h3>Name Your Store</h3>

            <input class="form-control" id="store" type="text">
             <h3>Name The Owner:</h3>

            <input class="form-control" id="owner" type="text">
        </div> // error on jsfiddle here
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="modalClose" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
        </div>
    </div> // and an error here
</div>
```

And my fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/boundlessvagabond/cjN4E/6/

Comment: The fiddle is only complaining because you technically didn't close your `input` tags. Try `<input class="form-control" id="owner" type="text" />`. I would recommend you run your HTML through a validator to easily find any markup issues.

Comment: There is no 'technical' error in this code. Something previous may be throwing it off. If you are going by Jsfiddle's syntax highlighter, it will throw you off a little. Its wanting to be like XML.

Comment: On the fiddle, you have a number of undefined variables and aren't including the Bootstrap JavaScript portion.  Once I cleaned that up, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I added this Java script line and it's working for me

```
    $('#onLoadModal').modal('show');
```

you can take a look at  http://jsbin.com/qobevoya/1/edit?html,js,output or the same example on http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=HvliL9wTPc

PS : you forget to add a bootstrap javascript file